# Can a PHP app be compatible to PHP5 and PHP7 at the same time?

Tags: php, upgrade

I have a complicated custom PHP app written for PHP5.

Can an app be modified to be compatible with both PHP5 and PHP7?

The background is that the server runs PHP5. What if it was upgraded to PHP7, could the upgrade be seamless.

Comment: I think the best practice is to select one target version of PHP. Each time before update app copy should be tested as much as possible. All errors should be checked & fixed. But one target PHP version should be defined as main requirement for server environment.

Comment: Unless you're using some pretty outdated code I don't think there's much in PHP7 that will outright break an app written for PHP5...

Comment: Yes it is possible. E.G. [Symfony 3](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely yes. But only if the app doesn't use PHP7 functions or syntax (In you issue it's only that). The best way to find out is to make a second server to test it out. An example: In Magento (big PHP app, I would say), there is only one line of code that crashes the app. This is a Syntax thing. But without testing out and reading the error log, you will most likely not finding it out by pure source code reading. I port multiple websites a week from PHP5 to PHP7. Most of the time the only problem is that some apps use MySQL instead of MySQLi (talking about the PHP-Modul. Not the Databases itself)

Answer (score 1):

From PHP5 to PHP7 is major version change. It would be surprise if the code worked as it is! As a starting point, you can see this http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php